# How is our site faring compared to other SE sites when it comes to daily traffic?

Tags: support, statistics, stackexchange

From [Area 51 stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) we can see that currently the visits per day for Hinduism.SE is 6,399 and which is considered as "excellent".

But compared to all other SE sites what is our exact position?

Comment: Go through [Stack Exchange communities list sorted based on Traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of traffic of all Stack Exchange sites is available on Stack Exchange site.

https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

As of today, our site is on #89 with 6.4k visits per day.

We can also know about traffic sources in [Site Analytics](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) which is gained at 5k reputation.